# Check if an element is contained in a tensor (Python Tensorflow2 with '@tf.function')

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm going to check if an  element is contained in a tensor, and I get problems.

e.g. 1

```
def foo(a):
    if 5 in tf.constant([5, 7, 9]):
        tf.print(a)

foo(2)

# you'll get '2', and no erros
```

e.g. 2

```
@tf.function
def foo(a):
    if 5 in tf.constant([5, 7, 9]):
        tf.print(a)

foo(2)

# you'll get erros like "TypeError: argument of type 'Tensor' is not iterable"
```

Apparently, things are different after adding **@tf.function**. I would be very grateful if you could help me solve this problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are decorating a function with @tf.function it will run in graph mode. In graph mode you cannot iterate over a tf.Tensor (that's what you're doing in your if statement).

Comment: Thanks for repling! But is there any way  to iter a tf.Tensor?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do. In your example you could use tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(5, tf.constant([5,7,9])) and use the result in a conditional statement (tf.cond).